# OpenCV: imread() works with argv but not with loading filename

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to opencv and trying the basic image read function. Here is the following code i used,

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 const char* filename = "pattern.png";
 Mat src = imread(filename, 0);
 if(src.data)
 {
    imshow("image_display",src);
    waitKey();
 }
 else
     cout<<"\n error in loading the file";
 return 0;
}
```

After debugging , i am seeing that the src.data is NULL.
But when i try to use the argv[1] option and run the .exe file in command window with the image name to loaded its working fine.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 Mat src = imread(argv[1], 0);
 if(src.data)
 {
    imshow("image_display",src);
    waitKey();
 }
 else
     cout<<"\n error in loading the file";
 return 0;
}
```

Can you please let me know what is wrong in the first code. I would like to work with my first code , since i can use visual studio debugging option.
Opencvversion:opencv-2.4.11

Comment: When you run the program in command window you are in a different folder that when you start the program in visual studio. Try using the full path in the first case (or put the image in the project dir).

Comment: @Miki I have placed the image where the .exe file is generated and I have used the full path also. I am facing the same issue

Comment: The image must be in the project directory (not the Debug or Release dir) if you want to access it just by name launching from VS. If you added the full path, make sure you used "\\" or "/" as separators

Comment: Did you pass the argument??

Comment: @Miki Thanks :) it works. Stupid mistake from my side, there were two folders once where .sln files and other where .vcxproj is present. Intially i tried where .sln files is present and it failed. Now it works, thanks again

Comment: @Arjun for argument passing , it worked with no issues.